# KendoUI Grid aggregate in Angular

Tags: kendo-ui, aggregate

I am using KendoUI grid and trying to get count on a field. I am getting sum on another field, which does not throw any error. Surprisingly, count also returns value but gives bunch of errors in console - **TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined**. Here is my HTML, please advise:

```
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
            [pageSize]="state.take"
            [skip]="state.skip"
            [sort]="state.sort"
            [sortable]="true"
            [pageable]="true"
            [scrollable]="'scrollable'"
            [groupable]="true"
            [group]="state.group"
            [filterable]="true"
            [filter]="state.filter"
            (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
            [height]="500">
    <kendo-grid-column field="EmployeeID" title="Employee ID" width="150" filter="numeric">
        <ng-template kendoGridFooterTemplate
                     let-column="column">Tot Reps:{{aggregates["EmployeeID"].count}}</ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="TotalHours" title="Total Hours" width="150" filter="numeric">
        <ng-template kendoGridGroupFooterTemplate
                     let-group="group"
                     let-aggregates>Sum:{{aggregates["TotalHours"].sum}}</ng-template>
        <ng-template kendoGridFooterTemplate
                     let-column="column">Tot Hours:{{total["TotalHours"]?.sum}}</ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: The `kendoGridFooterTemplate` does not provide `aggregates`-data to the template content. Did you declare `aggregates` in your component?

Comment: yes, I get aggregates from service

Comment: Is the HTML syntax correct?

Comment: Looks good to me, but w/o an actual running example it's hard to tell. But you can try to change `aggregates["EmployeeID"].count` to `aggregates["EmployeeID"]?.count` (guess, based on the error you get)

Comment: @Philipp, worked! thanks